# comparing values of a dataframe and storing them into seperate dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe and i'm trying to compare 2 rows (the 'high' between the two) at a time and store the values into another dataframe.

so basically in the new dataframe i would like
'386.575'
'383.5289'
etc

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be done using groupby to group the DF into groups of 2 rows and then selecting the row with the max `'high'`. The integer division of the index arranges the groups of 2 rows :

```
df2 = df.iloc[df.groupby(df.index//2)['high'].agg(pd.Series.idxmax)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something such as:

```
# Stores new data in array for dataframe
highValues = []

for i in range(0, len(df), 2):

    # Checks to see which "high" is higher
    if (df.loc[i].at["high"] > df.loc[i+1].at["high"]):
        # Appends data to array
        newDataFrame.append(df.loc[i].at["high"])

    if (df.loc[i].at["high"] < df.loc[i+1].at["high"]):
        # Appends data to array
        newDataFrame.append(df.loc[i+1].at["high"])

# Creates new pandas dataframe with array contents
newDF = pd.DataFrame(highValues)
```